# stay active on clicking list with href

Tags: css, addclass

I had a question about letting clicked buttons/lists/anchors stay in a different colour... This one is answered by FAngel, for which I thank again. Now, I have a different problem regarding the same issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/fxTQL/7/

In this fiddle, the effect is the exact effect as I want, but, on my website, it won't work. I guess I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it. My site has a frame in which topics/posts are fetched if I click on the buttons which you can see on the jsfiddle. So the page "refreshes" and shows the links. This however, makes it impossible to let the clicked links in a different colour. It goes automatically back to the first list item, which has already a background-color

How could I solve this problem?

This is something I considered.

```
<ul id="quick-index-list">
<li<? if(!$_GET['t']||$_GET['t']=='') echo ' class="active"';?>>
<a target="left" href="left">all</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using PHP, so you can retrieve the "t" variable's value.

You can use it to assign the "active" class to the `li` element which was selected:

```
<ul id="quick-index-list" class="pills slim muted">
<li<? if(!$_GET['t']||$_GET['t']=='') echo ' class="active"';?>>
<a id="qindex-popular" title="alle entries" target="left" href="left.php">alles</a>
</li>
<li<? if($_GET['t']=='tod') echo ' class="active"';?>>
<a id="qindex-today" title="entries van vandaag" target="left" href="left.php?t=tod">vandaag</a>
</li>
<li class="yesterday<? if($_GET['t']=='yes') echo ' active"';?>">
<a id="qindex-yesterday" title="entries van gisteren" target="left" href="left.php?t=yes">gisteren</a>
</li>
<li<? if($_GET['t']=='mix') echo ' class="active"';?>>
<a id="qindex-day" title="willekeurige entries" target="left" href="left.php?t=mix">willekeurig</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

So the class "active" on page load is already assigned to the correct `li` with:

```
<? if($_GET['t']=='tod') echo ' class="active"';?> /* default element */
```

or

```
<? if($_GET['t']=='tod') echo ' class="active"';?> /* anoter element */
```

when you already have a class on the `li`, just use

```
<li class="yesterday<? if($_GET['t']=='yes') echo ' active"';?>">
```

Be careful to echo spaces *before* the class name or the class attribute. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is almost working. The first three list items are going to an active state if clicked and they are staying that way, but if I use this code and I click on today, it will also make the last item (willekeurig) active. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Sorry, i made an typing error. Check the new code, it should work ;)

Comment: It is working indeed. Thank you very much GionaF, much appreciated!